# moving a files from one folder to another

Tags: c#

I am taking a file with a name of `sfile`

In  my method I am doing like this way

```
File.Copy(sSFile, Failure + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(sSFile)) ''''''''''FAILURE FOLDER"""""
                fileCounter += 1
File.move(sSFile, BACKup + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(sSFile)) ''''''''''BACKup FOLDER"""""
                fileCounter += 1
```

where failure and backup are different folders 
But it iss throwing an error : *This process is using by some other process*

Comment: Process used by other process, or **file** is in use by other process?

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 1):

Look at MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx). Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Path First, and then Copy the File, and then do the Same then Move the File.

I am guessing your trying to get the Filename when your already holding on to it to Copy and or Move It.

Comment: Can be the reson, two functions ont he same file.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`File.Copy(sSFile, Path.Combine(Failure, Path.GetFileName(sSFile)), bool_overrideflag);`